# Publish errors with the Faye-Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

I'm using the [faye-rails](https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails) gem for asynchronous messaging between the javascript in my frontend and my rails server. I can send messages using curl and have the javascript print them, so I know the faye server is running. I can also listen to messages on the server like this:

```
# In application.rb
config.middleware.use FayeRails::Middleware, mount: '/bayeux', :timeout => 25 do
  map '/async/**' => FayeController
  map :default => :block
end

# In faye_controller.rb
class FayeController < FayeRails::Controller
  channel '/async/test' do
    subscribe do
      puts "Received on channel #{channel}: #{message.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

Then I receive messages sent via `curl -X POST localhost:3000/bayeux -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"channel": "/async/test", "data": "test123"}'` and get the expected output. However, I can't seem to send messages from within the server. I expected somthing like this to work, in the subscribe block (so it would be sent as a response to any message):

```
FayeController.publish '/async/test', :response => 'something'
```

but that crashes the whole server with an error:

```
in '+': no implicit conversion of nil into Array (TypeError)
```

and then a stack trace. Is this my fault - am I failing to set something up correctly, or misreading the documentation? Or is it a bug in the gem, in which case does anyone have a workaround?

I've actually alread had to use one workaround already due to a bug in the underlying faye library, see [here](https://github.com/faye/faye/commit/cee6a778876da69ff958514b6591e6fcbf7481c1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish to faye server using an HTTP request (like curl) from your server

```
    uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/bayeux")
    begin
      Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, response: 'something')
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
      puts "Pushing to Faye Failed"
    end
```

--------- Update --------------------------

The previous code needs to be run in another thread to prevent the deadlock (run it in a back ground job using `resque` for example)

You can use the following to publish in the same thread

```
 client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:3000/bayeux')
 client.publish('/async/test', {response: "something"})
```

Comment: How could I modify this to work in production? It's not feasible for me to hardcode the URL of the server into a string.

Comment: Additionally, trying to use this deadlocks the server - I had to `kill -9` it

Comment: For the url hardcoding you can use the multiple environment configuration files `config/environments/development.rb` , `config/environments/production.rb` to add a configuration for faye server `config.faye_server= 'YOUR_SERVER_URL'` then refer to this using `Rails.configuration.faye_server`

Comment: Alright, that worked! A few gotchas: publishing on the channel that you're listening to creates an infinite loop (whoops); and to avoid creating a new client every time you get a message, you can create one as a class (static) variable and reference it inside the subscribe blocks. Thanks!